# Are Storyboards a good idea for apps that access the cloud?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboardsegue

I'm just about to delve into the world of app development (I'm usually a game developer) in iOS, and I've read the debates of using Storyboards Vs doing it programmatically, and I get for simple apps Storyboards is the way to go, but what about for Apps that access a server? and need to do lots of things dynamically? it seems most Apps these days would be like that, if that's the case are Storyboards  a good idea in that situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember that Storyboards are not an alternative to code. They are a tool that can be used along with coded view, nibs, etc...

The real skill comes in using all of these in such a way that takes least effort and gives most maintainability, readability and reliability.

Many of my apps combine several storyboards and a lot of nibs.

Having said that. Nothing that can be done in a storyboard should be anywhere near any cloud code.

The classes that access the cloud should not change whether you are coding views using nibs or using storyboards.

The article that was linked in the other answer is very odd indeed. To dismiss storyboards as things that are only used for prototyping is just plain wrong.

A well structured app (or part of an app) that access some network stuff should be modelled something like...

[Networking stuff]----[View Controller Stuff]----[View Stuff]

It doesn't matter whether the view controller is created in a storyboard, nib or in code. The networking stuff is unchanged.

Also, the article mentions "custom views" as something that you can't do with Storyboards. Again, that's just wrong. My latest app Emojicate was written using a combination of Storyboards (the project has 2 storyboards), nibs (for custom cells etc...) and a couple of coded views (the emoji message view is coded).

It sounds like the guy writing that hasn't really looked into the various tools in any amount of detail.

Comment: Thanks. I take what you're saying, a lot of people say Storyboards are good for the obvious things, but you can run into trouble when you're trying to use dynamic data with them. Most of the apps I make will use the cloud in some way so I'm just wondering if it's better to just go with doing everything programmatically, or take the plunge and learn Storyboards properly.

Comment: @Phil if by "dynamic data" you mean stuff that can come from the network and may be delayed or of a different size etc... then it is purely a case of developing your app to allow for this. The same considerations have to be made whether creating a view controller in code or through a storyboard. Also, the only part of the creation of the view controller that a storyboard does is in adding subViews and connecting properties etc... Most of that is just boilerplate code anyway. If you have a concrete example of what you are thinking I'd be more than happy to address it specifically.

Comment: I'll be working on a simple App UI wise, so it will have a TabController, 5 tabs, table views etc, but all the data will come in via Parse.com, and it will allow for user profiles, display of maps etc. Also needs to work universally.

Comment: @Phil Emojicate uses Parse.com as a back end also and has a TabBarController as the main interface. Most of it uses storyboards. The thing to remember with any app like that (no matter how you write it) is that you have to be ready for there not to be any data available (phone offline etc...) This is the only real consideration. I use networking classes that are separate from view controllers because it allows them to be reused. Also, storyboards and size classes (in Xcode 6) allow for designing universal UIs inside a single storyboard. Take a look at Ray Wenderlich tutorials about them.

Comment: Thanks for the info it's appreciated. So you don't use multiple storyboards? I've read some use more than 1. Do you use the Parse subclasses for tables etc? or roll your own?

Comment: @Phil I do actually. I tend to use single storyboards for different "workflows" of the app. So in my app I have a "login and on boarding workflow" and a "main app workflow". Because the main part of the app is relatively small I only need one for all of it. Then I have a singleton class that is loaded by the app delegate and works out which storyboard to present to the screen. (if the user is logged in etc...) Also, when I log out this class "switches" to the login storyboard.

Comment: @Phil in the past I have created a single storyboard for work flows like searching for items over the network. Where there may be several steps to it. Or creating new objects where different tables are required for the different properties and stuff..

Comment: You know this sort of information is hardly available online, it's all technically how to set things up etc but not best strategies etc. Do you use the Parse sign up/sign in classes? And your app is called Emojicate on the App store? I'll check it out :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65956/discussion-between-fogmeister-and-phil).

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the this article. I think it's summarised really nice and briefly the pros and cons:
http://andrewrauh.com/2013/09/01/storyboardsnibs-vs-doing-everything-with-code-in-ios/